# Error: origin_mismatch

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, oauth-2.0

When I try to access to my project in google map engine form my server 
its make "Error: origin_mismatch"
I made the origin of JavaScript http://myserver.com
and the request details appear in the error is the same origin. 
What is the problem?

Reqest Details

```
immediate=false
response_type=token
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mapsengine
redirect_uri=postmessage
proxy=oauth2relay424201031
state=730496938|0.115543733
origin=http://myserver.com
include_granted_scopes=true
client_id=720390775172-erkkro00391rvru1stipgch25jkrnqke.apps.googleusercontent.com
authuser=0
```

Comment: What did you set the Javascript Origins to in the Google Developer console?

Comment: The same as my server name "testoca.com"

Comment: try adding www.   https://www.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

origin_mismatch is normally caused by the Javascript origins not being set correctly [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) for the project. You need to make sure that the Javascript origins match the domain from which your requests are coming and to which you are returning the user after sign in.

It must exactly match what appears in your browser.

http://www.testoca.com or https://www.testoca.com

[image]

in this picture it would be https://www.example.com that is the origin.

Note: if there is a port number that must also be added  http://www.testoca.com:1234

Comment: I do that ant its not working 
the url in the browser show that
the orgine is still http://testoca.com ??
its the same in the console like my server

Comment: Wait for couple minutes after adding origin. Some changes in Google Developers Console are not instantaneous. It took me 2 minutes before my new origin was valid for signing in.